# Does Google News index HTML5 websites?

Tags: html5, google-news

Does anyone know if Google News properly indexes HTML5 websites?

For example, since HTML5 allows for  to have an h1 tag (instead of having it where the heading tags are done downward, i.e. the article gets h1, a sub section would get h2, the sidebar navigation gets h3, etc.), if I had the  tag have an h1, would Google News get confused or do they already support  and would notice the h1 and index as they normally do for an HTML4/XHTML page?

Comment: Not following you, what is the difference between how HTML5 handles H1 tags, and other HTML versions? Here's the W3C specs: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements

Comment: From what I've read and know, on HTML4/XHTML pages, you normally have the <h1> tag on an article be the page's title.

But from what I'm reading, each of the section tags (article, aside, etc.) can have h1 --- i.e. having the headings ranked by each section instead of globally.

Unless I'm understanding this completely wrong or something.

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.org/semantics.html Found the article I was referring to. The "top" <header> has a h1, but the one in <article>'s <header> also has an h1. So my question would be, does Google News parse HTML5 correctly and notice <article> and looks for the h1, instead of finding multiple h1's and getting confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure google can and will index your content. I'm not sure if google will give more weight to article's h1 instead of header's h1 for SEO.

Keep in mind that title tag is more important (in SEO weight) than h1 headings.

Note that what goes to google results are tags title and meta tag description. Other tags are for weightning only. And as rule of thumb, how close to page's start are they keywords, the best.

It could be interesting add an H1 to the header element, from SEO ponit of view.

Comment: Thanks, that answer helped out quite bit. And for this layout there isn't an h1 in the header, so the first h1 wouldn't occur until the actual article.

Answer (score 0):

Google can index everything, HTMLs, PDFs, XLSs etc. So yes it can index your page. But will it index it in the best way for SEO is another issue.